# Matio performance

Tags: mat-file, mnist

I am trying to read MNIST data-set (size is 784*60000) my implementation of reading MNIST binary format takes around 20 secs, but I tried to use Matio library to read same data-set in .mat format and it takes much longer about 4~5 min. this is how I try to read the mat file. Am I doing something wrong?

Matrix struct

```
struct Matrix {
size_t col;
size_t row;
float *members;

Matrix() {
  members = NULL;
  col = 0;
  row = 0;
}
};
```

Reading the mat file

```
mat_t *openmatfp;
matvar_t *mymat;
Matrix matrix;
openmatfp = Mat_Open("trainingdata.mat",MAT_ACC_RDONLY);
matrix.row = mymat->dims[0];
matrix.col = mymat->dims[1];
matrix.elements = new float[matrix.row * matrix.col];
memcpy(matrix.members, mymat->data,mymat->nbytes);//problem should be here!
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing does not set mymat.

You need something like:
 mymat = Mat_VarRead(openmatfp, "MatrixName");